# There is no role named `admin`. laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

i use this package :

> https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/tree/v2

code :

```
     $user=User::find(2);
    $user->assignRole('admin');
```

and when i assign admin role to user  I'm dealing with this error

> There is no role named `admin`.Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist

this is my default guard in auth.php :

```
    <?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

this is my roles table :

[image]

this is my role_has_permission table

[image]

and this is my permission table :

[image]

Comment: @kerbholz please check my post again thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

just add this protected property to your user model(or whatever model you are using for assigning permissions and roles).

`protected $guard_name = 'api';`

Comment: This works perfectly well. A quote from the documentation "If you’re using multiple guards the guard_name attribute needs to be set as well. Read about it in the using multiple guards section of the readme". 

link https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/multiple-guards

Answer (score 1):

Add one of the following to your `User` model:

```
public $guard_name = 'api';
```

Or:

```
public function guardName()
{
  return 'api';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a convention it's best to do configurable things in the config file.
The problem with your code is the order of arranging your guards, just re-arrange as seen below.

```php
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
 ...
```

Once this is done, you don’t need to add `protected $guard_name = 'api';` to your **User** model, ensure to run `php artisan config:clear`

Ref: [Saptie Laravel Permisions](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/multiple-guards#the-downside-to-multiple-guards)

Answer (score 1):

friends! I found solution for this problem but first of all, i illustrate why this problem happened. As you know, Laravel read the codes from top to bottom and from left to right. Moreover when we want from laravel fresh all data by command

```
php artisan migrate :fresh --seed
```

It clears all this data and the problem begin. By other word, when assign Role command to check for new role it fails because all data is cleared before it access to those data. To avoid this we should set Role seeder class before Admin seeder class in database seeder

```php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
       $this->call([RoleSeeder::class, AdminSeeder::class]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your user model

```
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
```

and in a user model class

```
use HasRoles;
```

Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67650791/15950737)

[Complete example](https://ateequrrahman150.medium.com/spatie-permissions-with-laravel-f3eda6694d4)

Comment: You cant get error described in question without using trait you specified, so you are not answering to the question

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
$role = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'admin', 'name' => 'manager']);
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).